# Mutlidimensional associative arrays in typescript

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use a multidimensional associative array that was passed from php to the frontend so I have created a new type as follows:

```js
type AssociativeArray<T = unknown> = { [key: string]: AssociativeArray<T> | T | undefined | T[] };
```

When I try to compile the following code:

```js
type AssociativeArray<T = unknown> = { [key: string]: AssociativeArray<T> | T | undefined | T[] };

const exampleStatusJSON: AssociativeArray<string> = {
  available: "true",
  username: "Jean-loup",
  house: {
    room: {
      name: "Highcrest",
    },
  }
};

if ((typeof (exampleStatusJSON["house"]) !== "undefined") &&
            (typeof (exampleStatusJSON["house"]["room"]) !== "undefined") &&
            (typeof (exampleStatusJSON["house"]["room"]["name"]) !== "undefined")) {
    console.log("OK");
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznA9gYwJYENioG4RgJ33RAB4AVKAXigFcA7AazsQHc6A+KqAbygG0GEEAC4ocYPlR0A5gF1R8JGkw48hYuU4AfKBR30AJhABmUiAag6yfWVAC+AbgCwAKFfJEdcVAgAPdAC2YAA2EADKwJg0cABSYQDyAHIKCCgYWLgERKTikjKc1NyuUFDo2OiowegARqGiAEQSNBD1ADTFtHAQ+HSBEA0xEOh0ALTBiDRgbR0AFhNdokUuJSX4iIgBix0rUL0B-VD1ABKo0jPI+BDi08srdu23dq6Orq6oxlAAFJ+gkIgfnz8gRC4UiwGicSSfHqc2iLVkAEooABCSjUeqGExmAz1JEAMjx2x2xJ+4Ag-y+QKCoQiUViCUS0NhXXqsmhaw2rKRqPRmNMdHMuKgBKJxJWpL+AKpINp4PpUJh83h7PWAVZ0L28O5aMOfOxuKRSx2Hi8iFCADpxtJPvV4gBpXHOFx2IA)

typescript throws an error in the second and third condition:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"room"' can't be used to index type 'string | AssociativeArray<string> | string[]'.
Property 'room' does not exist on type 'string | AssociativeArray<string> | string[]'.(7053)
```

What would be the best way to describe such arrays in typescript?

Comment: Your type definition is correct, but the result of `exampleStatusJSON["house"]` is of type `string | AssociativeArray<string> | string[]`. Since the compiler doesn't know that the result is `AssociativeArray<string>` in this particular case, it doesn't allow you to index it with an arbitrary string. You can use `(... as AssociativeArray<string>)["room"]` to force the type, although it gets pretty verbose that way.

Comment: You are right. I thought it was a problem with the recursive type. As soon as I force the type it works as expected.